# Implementing bounded generic with java

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface

```
public interface TransferObjectUtil<B extends BusinessObject,T> {

    public T to(B domain);

    public B from(T transferObject);
}
```

I am implementing the class for this as

```
public class ReflectionBasedTransferObjectUtil<B extends BusinessObject, T> implements
    **TransferObjectUtil<B extends BusinessObject, T>** {
```

For the portion within the ** in the above line the compiler complains that for B extends BusinessObject is not allowed. Why would it be so ?

I am just starting with generics, so pardon me for my novice question.

Answer (score 1):

Your location for the generics is a bit wrong / overeager, try it like this

```
public class ReflectionBasedTransferObjectUtil<B extends BusinessObject, T> implements TransferObjectUtil<B, T> {
```

Comment: yeah it works, but why so ? Because in the interface definition  I have declared as B extends BusinessObject so while implementing why does it give an error ? Just want to know why that syntax is wrong and what does the correct syntax mean .